# Explanation of shift operationals use in condition

Tags: c++, c, binary, shift

I have a c code given to me to fill for my thesis. Can you please explain what the following segment does, because i'm very buffled with it.

```
int i;
_int8 codeword[64800];

//loop running through codeword
if (codeword[i << 1] << 1 | codeword[i << 1 | 1])
    {
      //more code here
    }
```

where i is a loop counter and 
codeword[] is an 1d matrix of ones and zeros

I mostly seek explanation of the operations taking place if, for example, codeword[i] is 1.

Comment: @user2079303 Given the access pattern here, I'd say it's a heap.

Comment: If you are confused, split it up into several lines and use temp booleans, preferably ones with meaningful names, to avoid 'one-liner' compound expressions.

Comment: The second shift in first expression is unnecessary as any Nonzero value will make the condition true

Comment: @PeterJ If `codeword[i << 1]` is `unsigned` with only its MS bit set, `codeword[i << 1] << 1` is not true, so the `if()` depends on the next element.

Comment: @Christos Mordons Post lacks context and what types are `codeword, i`?

Comment: without the declaration of `i` and `codeword` any answer would have to do some guessing. You just need to add few lines to make it an [mcve]

Comment: Is the middle `|` intentional or should it be '||'?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  In C, `<<` is the bit shift left operator.  In C++, you can overload the operator (for example, for I/O it is overloaded).

Comment: Original post edited. Sorry for the inconvenience as this is my first post ever. The code is C.

Answer (score 1):

The test combines the 2 bits in `codeword` at offset `2 * i` and `2 * i + 1` and evaluates the body if they are not both `0`.  The expression is parsed as:

```
int i;
_int8 codeword[64800];

//loop running through codeword
if ((codeword[i << 1] << 1) | codeword[(i << 1) | 1]) {
    // more code here
}
```

Note that the expression would be equivalent but more readable as:

```
int i;
_int8 codeword[64800];

//loop running through codeword
if (codeword[2 * i] || codeword[2 * i + 1]) {
    // more code here
}
```